# liminf and limsup

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

let $x_n$ be a series and :

$b<=x_n<=c$ for all but a finite number of n, show that $b<=\liminf{x_n}$

My approach :

So since $x_n$ is bounded by the interval $[b,c]$ $x_n$ it's greatest lower bound could be at max $b$ right? Since lower bounds for $x_n$ has a greatest point, and that greatest point is in the closure of $x_n$ and since we are in a closed interval in real numbers only, that would be $b$.

It all seems proving this is quite easy in this way, but How would I prove it mathematically?

Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $N$ so that $k\geqslant N$ implies $x_k\geqslant b$. Then $\inf_{k\geqslant N} x_k\geqslant b$, and so $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty}\inf_{k\geqslant n}x_k\geqslant b. $$